# set tint colors for uinavigation bar in iOS 7 with out inturupting barbutton items

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7, xcode5

I tried to set navigation bar colour to black in iOS 7 using

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

using this not working

but some times works but all the other bar buttons remains in black, which cause not able to see the bar buttons

Comment: Are you trying to set the tint of the buttons or of the navigation bar.

Comment: "some times" is a vague term. You should explain it properly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check [Apple document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TransitionGuide/Bars.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013174-CH8-SW1) , you got info

Default navigationBar in iOS7 is translucent and its background control by barTinColor

So to make your navigationBar black like iOS6, you can do

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:NO];

[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

Or

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackOpaque];
```

Comment: [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackOpaque];

This works fine for set color but, back button & navigation bar button items are not visable they are in their default color black

Comment: Maybe you setTinColor to black ? TinColor now use for BarItem in iOS7, just delete setTinColor in your code or set it to different color

Answer (score 3):

In iOS7:

`[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];`

Comment: This works for me, but makes the time and the battery black so you can't see it anymore. Why?

Comment: That's because you need to set he status bar style to light content. Set the style of the navigation bar to black, and it will happen automatically.